# Set Script Type in MVC4 Script Bundle

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox

I'm using the new `ScriptBundle` class in MVC4, along with `@Styles.Render()` and `@Scripts.Render()`.

This has worked great for me so far, until I ran into this issue in Firefox :

`If tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).`

Sure enough, when I looked on any page where I'm using the `.Render()` helper, all of my javascripts are being outputted as :

```
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.validate.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.dropdown.js">
<script src="/WestingProject/Scripts/jquery.placeholder.js">
```

Here is how I have them defined in the `BundleConfig.cs` class :

```
bundles.Add(
            new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dropdown.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.placeholder.js"));
```

**My Question :**

Using the script bundle, is there any way I can add the `type="text/javascript"` attribute to all of my javascripts when they're outputted to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

`<script src="@Scripts.Url("~/bundles/jquery")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Although, this will minify and bundle your scripts, so will inhibit debugging the javascript if needed.