# How to get the ASP.NET MVC bundle manager to render a script tag with the type = "module" attribute?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When we add a bundle to the ASP.NET MVC bundle collection like so:

```
public static RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{

  bundles.Add( new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/foo")
               .Include("~/Scripts/foo.js"));
}
```

And render it in a view like so:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/foo")
```

It gets rendered like a regular javascript file inclusion `<script>` like so:

```
<script src = "/Scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

But my **foo.js** is an ES 6 module and so I'd like it to load like so:

```
<script src = "/Scripts/foo.js" type = "module"></script>
```

Short of typing that `<script>` tag myself, how do I actually get the ASP.NET MVC bundle classes to render it this way?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.4 targeting the .NET framework version 4.6.1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assumed that you have latest `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` package installed, hence you could use [`Scripts.RenderFormat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj659006(v%3Dvs.110)) to add `type` attribute on generated `<script>` tag:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='{0}' type='module'></script>", "~/bundle/foo")
```

Or you could utilize a helper class containing helper method to render `<script>` tags with additional attribute for certain bundles:

```
public static class ScriptHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString RenderWithTypeAttribute(params string[] paths)
    {
        return System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(@"<script src=""{0}"" type=""module""></script>", paths);
    }
}
```

And then use it in Razor view page like this:

```
@ScriptHelpers.RenderWithTypeAttribute("~/bundle/foo")
```

Reference:

[How to render Scripts/Styles bundles in the custom format in ASP.NET MVC?](http://techfunda.com/howto/297/scriptbundle-stylebundle-in-custom-format)

Related issue:

[Set Script Type in MVC4 Script Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333592/set-script-type-in-mvc4-script-bundle)